# Filter out / hide OR replace excel dax measure 0 values

Tags: excel, filter, powerbi, dax, measure

I have the following dax measure in the value area of a pivot table to return a concatenated list of unique values from a table:

```
=CONCATENATEX(
    Values(
    Table1[Column2]
    ),
    Table1[Column2],", "
)
```

There are instances where 0 is returned as the value because no corresponding values exists for that row in the source data.

Is it possible to either replace with "-" or preferrably hide or filter out these rows entirely.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume something simple like =IF(your_formula=0, "", your_formula) does not work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. My list contains text values.

"This formula is invalid or incomplete: 'Calculation error in measure 'Table1'[Measure1]: DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.'.

Comment: So `Column2` is a text column but has numeric `0` rather than text `"0"` in it?